# Skip route table

Tags: virtualbox, iptables, routing

I want to create a VM VBOX Ubuntu to be a gateway in my home lan to route to my enterprise VPN.
The problem is that my VPN when is stablished, create a route per route entry with metric 1 to be routed to the VPN. In this way local routing is disabled. If you modify or create a route, the VPN disconnects. I want to know if anybody see any solution, for instance using iptables.

I see in a tcpdump that the problem is with the return packets, the destination responses, but this response is not routed. I have enable ip_forward and tried:
iptables -A FORWARD -i tun0 -o eth0 -d 192.168.0.0/24 -j ACCEPT

But this doesnt work, nothing changes.

Regards

Answer (score 0):

Finally iptables seems not be my solution, thus iptables filters, marks, but not routes.

I think it is necesary to tune ip routing. If there is an expert in routing policies in linux i will appreciate the help. I will try to experiments the ip rule command.

Answer (score 0):

Finally i get it.
Create a custom route table, and an ip rule that traffic to local net goes to my custom route table. The VPN checker doesnt modify my custom route table.
For anybody who wants to do the same:
https://www.lartc.org/howto/lartc.rpdb.html